# Jersey ClientResponse Get List of Composite Entities

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

I am trying to get a Result of a List, basically a list of entities using Jersey RESTful API (Server and Client)

```
UserRESTClient client = new UserRESTClient();
ClientResponse response = client.getUsersByType(ClientResponse.class, String.valueOf(userType));
List<User> participants = response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<User>>() {
    });
```

However, the above code does not work if Entity User has a Composite Object, if for instance,

```
public class User {
  private UserId userId;
}
public class UserId {
  private int id;
  private int categoryId;
}
```

In this case, the JSON is deserialized by Jersey and returned null for the field type **UserId** inside Class User. I inspected the JSON returned and everything seems good at the RESTful Server end, but the nested JSON response is not clearly processed at the Client.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not sure if it because of the Jackson preprocessor.

Following is the actual Code Snippet. It involves two classes Participant and ParticipantPK (primary for each Participant).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conference_participant")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Participant.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Participant p"),

public class Participant implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @EmbeddedId
  protected ParticipantPK participantPK;
}

@Embeddable
public class ParticipantPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "conference_id")
    private int conferenceId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 150)
    @Column(name = "participant_sip_uri")
    private String participantSipUri;

    public ParticipantPK() {
    }

    public ParticipantPK(int conferenceId, String participantSipUri) {
        this.conferenceId = conferenceId;
        this.participantSipUri = participantSipUri;
    }
```

And the Code for retrieving ClientResponse,

```
 List<Participant> participants = response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<Participant>>() {
    });
```

However, the ParticipantPK (Composite PK) is null.

Answer (score 4):

You only pasted a code snippet so I don't know if this part is excluded, but in my code I didn't have setters for the fields.  I had getters, but no setters.

Without the setters, my composite objects themselves were non-null, but the members of those objects were themselves null.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce it, but using the same data structures worked for me. What version of Jersey are you using? Is User class annotated with @XmlRootElement or are you using the POJO mapping feature?

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you so much for your effort. I am using @@Entity @@XmlRootElement. Could you please refer back to the question for the Code Snippet of the class?

Comment: Which container are you using for your server side? If GlassFish, which version? Is the client also deployed as a web app? Or is it a desktop/commandline app?

Comment: JSF, Glassfish v3.1.1 Thank you.

Comment: Do you think everything else seems fine, from the above code? Is there a way to get the JSON that I receive and deserialize it to Entity using Gson or something? (Because I know that REST Facade is sending the data right). Thank you.

Comment: What version of Jersey are you using on the client? Or is client running in GlassFish 3.1.1 as well? (i.e. using Jersey from GlassFish)

Comment: Client => Glassfish v3.1.1 
Server => Sailfin v2.1

As for Server is bundled with the following jar (as a part of its runtime, I guess)
jersey-bundle-1.0.3.1
jettison-1.0.1
jsr311-api-1.0

However, I have added,
jersey-bundle-1.12
jettison-1.1
jsr311-api-1.1.1

On the Client, all the APIs are Jersey v1.12

Is there anything I need to do to override the previous version on the Sailfin server? The problem still persists :(

Thank you.

Comment: Ah, that's an ancient version of Jersey you have on the server. But you are saying you think what server produces is correct and it is the client that can't read it? Can you post how the JSON sent from the server looks like?

Comment: Probably best to do this by filing an issue at http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY and attach the file there.